# Is there another possible way to display a webpage(selfwritten) not on localhost but on any mobile browser other then paying for a webserver?

Tags: three.js, webserver

I am starting to write my thesis and I will work using Blender and Three.js for the project. As it will have a gps functionality it would be better to run it on mobilephones' browsers. I would like to know if there is any other way to do that then through a paid webserver, or without simulation or there isn't.

Comment: You can also host it on a computer in the same network as the mobile phones. Is that an option for you?

Comment: I think yes that would be an option, but could you tell me how can I exactly do that?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a computer on your local network instead:

1. Set up a web server on your computer. Popular choices are [nginx](https://nginx.org/en/)
   or [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/).
2. Copy your files to the directory used by your web server.
3. Find out the IP address of that computer.
4. Enter that IP address in your mobile browser.

Of course those steps are very general, the concrete details depend on your operating system.

Comment: For a local server used in development, I think [simplehttpserver](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/modules-in-python/how-to-use-simplehttpserver/) or [live-server](https://github.com/tapio/live-server) are much easier to get started with than Apache or Nginx. Once (or if) you're ready to make the site live, use free hosting like GitHub Pages, Neocities, Glitch, etc.